How to save file in specific local path in client device from web app using react
I can't specify specific location to save a file in code(react).
I've constructed a web application with react and want to save a file to a certain folder directory.
When I was surfing the web, I discovered that it had never been done.

You can not control this part of browser behaviour. What if my OS does not even have that path? Different OS'es (e.g. Windows and Android)

@Justinas Yes, that is an acceptable point; but, if I receive the path once and then download a file and save it in that area, will it work?

No, you can not set save path from JS side. Also you sometimes can get C://fakepath/myfile.txt instead of actual path
